# Animate labels for 20 seconds

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have 3 labels binded like following

```
<StackLayout>

<Label Padding="1" Text="VRN"  FontSize="25" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/> 
                               
<Label Padding="1"  Text="{Binding VRN}" TextColor="#ba000d" FontSize="100" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

<Label  Padding="1" Text="Make" FontSize="25" TextColor="Black"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                
 <Label Text="{Binding Make}" TextColor="#ba000d" FontSize="100" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                              
  <Label Text="{Binding Model}" TextColor="#ba000d" FontSize="30" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Binding is done in ItemModel like following

```
string _vrn = "";
        public string VRN
        {
            protected set
            {
                if (_vrn != value)
                {
                    _vrn = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("VRN");
                }
            }
            get { return _vrn ; }
        }
        string _make= "";
        public string Make
        {
            protected set
            {
                if (_make!= value)
                {
                    _make= value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Make");
                }
            }
            get { return _make; }
        }
        string _model = "";
        public string Model
        {
            protected set
            {
                if (_model != value)
                {
                    _model = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Model");
                }
            }
            get { return _model ; }
        }
           hubConnection.On<string>("NewItem", (item) =>
            {
                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
         
                        Item newItem = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(item);    
                        VRN= newItem.VRN;
                        Make= newItem.Make;
                        Model= newItem.Model;
                 }
               }
```

Above code will set the labels with value of last item inserted. Up to here done.

I want to animate(Blink) the 3 labels for 20 seconds whenever new item is added to Item ObservableCollection(I am using SignalR to insert data)

I already have a class which i am using it with CollectionView for another scenario.Is there any way i can use the following class to animate Labels or is there any other easy way?

```
public class BlinkTriggerAction : TriggerAction<VisualElement>
{
    protected async override void Invoke(VisualElement sender)
    {
            var parentAnimation = new Animation();
            var fadeOutAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 1, 0, Easing.Linear);
            var fadeInAnimation = new Animation(d => sender.Opacity = d, 0, 1, Easing.Linear);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Commit(sender, "BlinkingVisualElement", 16, 800, repeat: () => true);
            await Task.Delay(20000);
            parentAnimation.Add(0, 0.5, fadeOutAnimation);
            parentAnimation.Add(0.5, 1, fadeInAnimation);
            sender.AbortAnimation("BlinkingVisualElement");

    }
}
```

Comment: If what you are looking is reusability of the same animation, I would recommend using Behaviors instead of Triggers. You can create Styled Behaviors and any element can use that style to animate your VisualElement.

Comment: Can you post a sample code using my code?

Comment: check the answer I posted, hope it solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for reusability I would suggest using behaviours instead of Triggers, as it lets you add it under the styles which Triggers don't.

Your BlinkTriggerBehavior would be something like this:
Note: I am using VisualElement here, you can use anything in future e.g Button, Label, Entry etc.

```
  public class BlinkTriggerBehavior: Behavior<VisualElement>
  {
    protected override void OnAttachedTo(VisualElement bindable)
    {
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
        bindable.PropertyChanged += Animate; // binding property changed event
    }

    private async void Animate(object obj, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // your animation code gets fired everytime any of your Label 
        // property changes or any VisualElement which uses this behavior.

        // If you wish you can use whatever property name you wish  here or keep your  
        //    animation code as is.
        if (e.PropertyName == "Text")
        {
            //Your animation code
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(VisualElement bindable)
    {
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
        bindable.PropertyChanged -= Animate;
    }
  }
```

In your MainPage.xaml, contentpage resource you can add the following:

```
         <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Behaviors>
                <views:BlinkTriggerBehavior />
            </Style.Behaviors>
        </Style>
        ... any other Target type Like you mentioned CollectionView ViewCell
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the animation for the label, you could download the source file from the link below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-animation-basic/

Change the xaml in `RotateAnimationPage` like below.

```
 <StackLayout Margin="0,20,0,0">
    <!--<Image x:Name="image" Source="monkey.png" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />-->
    <Label
        x:Name="image"
        BackgroundColor="Accent"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        Text="Hello"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
    <Button
        x:Name="startButton"
        Clicked="OnStartAnimationButtonClicked"
        Text="Start Animation"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
    <Button
        x:Name="cancelButton"
        Clicked="OnCancelAnimationButtonClicked"
        IsEnabled="false"
        Text="Cancel Animation"
        VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
</StackLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

And if you want to animate labels for **20 seconds**, you could set the `RotateTo` length which to animate the transition to `20000`. The screenshot set with 2000.

```
  await image.RotateTo(360, 20000);
```

Comment: Its not simple as that.I cant write animation code from code behind of XAML. Trigger should be in ItemViewModel. Clients can insert data from anywhere using SignalR. Same time i should animate the labels. I am setting the values already.Its only animation part is the issue